# AngularJS atrribute directive not evaluating expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create new directives which add/remove a class to an element based on result of an expression. Basically very similar to ng-hide and ng-show. My directive receives the expression but never parses it. Expression is always treated as a string.

```
App.directive('ngVisible',
function ($parse) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if ($parse(attrs.ngVisible))
            element.addClass("ng-visible");
        else
            element.addClass("ng-invisible");

        console.log('attrs.ngVisible', attrs.ngVisible);

        console.log('$eval result', scope.$eval(attrs.ngVisible));
    }

 }

);
```

First log statement shows the correct expression as a string.

Second log statement shows undefined.

Usage:

```
<span class="text-danger" ng-visible="companiesForm.cName.$error.required && company==editingCompany"><label class=" label label-danger">Name required</label></span>
```

Comment: OK. I just figured it out by looking at source code for ng-hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to similar stuff. Here is the final directive:

```
App.directive('ngVisible',
  function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngVisible, function (value) {

                if (value)
                    element.removeClass("ng-invisible");
                else
                    element.addClass("ng-invisible");

            });
        }
    }

});
```

Class:

```
.ng-invisible {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Usage:

```
<span ng-visible="companiesForm.cName.$error.required">Required!</span>
```

Comment: Any clear explanation as to why this is the solution? I am facing very similar and want to fully understand it first